# Finding earliest and latest date in range for multiple occurrences in same series

Tags: sql, oracle

My first question and I feel I'm not explaining it clearly, but the example data should.

How can I find the earliest date for one "type" before the earliest date of another "type", accounting for dates of the "same" type which should not be included, then the same for additional sequential dates in the series?

Example data in a table:

```
PERSON_ID  SERVICE_DATE SERVICE_TYPE
ABC        10/4/2018    INTAKE
ABC        10/8/2018    INTAKE
ABC        10/19/2018   DISCHARGE
ABC        10/25/2018   DISCHARGE
ABC        11/21/2018   INTAKE
ABC        12/3/2018    INTAKE
ABC        12/6/2018    INTAKE
ABC        12/26/2018   DISCHARGE
```

I would like to return:

```
PERSON_ID  INTAKE_DATE DISCHARGE_DATE
ABC        10/4/2018   10/19/2018
ABC        11/21/2018  12/26/2018
```

EDIT: Second example. If Intake and Discharge on same date, I would also like to capture that.

```
PERSON_ID  SERVICE_DATE  SERVICE_TYPE
DEF        10/1/2018     INTAKE
DEF        10/1/2018     DISCHARGE
DEF        11/5/2018     INTAKE
DEF        12/31/2018    DISCHARGE
```

I would like to return:

```
PERSON_ID  INTAKE_DATE DISCHARGE_DATE
DEF        10/1/2018   10/1/2018
DEF        11/5/2018   12/31/2018
```

Comment: You tagged [tag:plsql], are you using a stored procedure for this?

Comment: Yes, it is part of a loop in a procedure. I believe that is fine; I'm just interested in the sql (essentially the SELECT statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE to easily match patterns over multiple rows, like in the following query:

```
WITH test_vals AS (
    SELECT 'ABC' as PERSON_ID,TO_DATE('10/4/2018','mm/dd/yyyy') as SERVICE_DATE,'INTAKE' as SERVICE_TYPE FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 'ABC',TO_DATE('10/8/2018','mm/dd/yyyy'),'INTAKE' FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 'ABC',TO_DATE('10/19/2018','mm/dd/yyyy'),'DISCHARGE' FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 'ABC',TO_DATE('10/25/2018','mm/dd/yyyy'),'DISCHARGE' FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 'ABC',TO_DATE('11/21/2018','mm/dd/yyyy'),'INTAKE' FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 'ABC',TO_DATE('12/3/2018','mm/dd/yyyy'),'INTAKE' FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 'ABC',TO_DATE('12/6/2018','mm/dd/yyyy'),'INTAKE' FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 'ABC',TO_DATE('12/26/2018','mm/dd/yyyy'),'DISCHARGE' FROM DUAL
)

SELECT m.person_id,
       m.earliest_intake_date,
       m.earliest_discharge_date
FROM test_vals t
match_recognize (
    PARTITION BY person_id
    ORDER BY service_date, service_type DESC /* Order such that INTAKE comes before DISCHARGE if two items have the same service date */
    MEASURES
        MIN(service_date) AS earliest_intake_date,
        MAX(service_date) AS earliest_discharge_date
    ONE ROW PER match
    pattern (
        intake+ /* Match one or more INTAKE codes, followed by a DISCHARGE */
        discharge
    )
    define 
        intake AS service_type = 'INTAKE',
        discharge AS service_type = 'DISCHARGE'
) m
```

Comment: Thanks, @Josh Eller. I was not familiar with that analytic function but it appears to capture what I want, with one exception... If the Intake and Discharge date is the same, I would want to capture that, but the logic above does not. I added that example as an edit to my original question.

Comment: @dcox1524 I updated my answer. You just need to add another order by parameter, to make sure that if two items have the same date, the intake value comes before the discharge one

Comment: Ah, okay. That answered everything. I look forward to learning and using this function. Thank you!

Comment: @dcox1524 Glad I could help! If the answer solved your problem, please remember to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

with test_table as (
  select 'ABC' PERSON_ID, to_date('10/04/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') SERVICE_DATE,   'INTAKE'       SERVICE_TYPE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  select 'ABC' PERSON_ID, to_date('10/08/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') SERVICE_DATE,   'INTAKE'       SERVICE_TYPE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  select 'ABC' PERSON_ID, to_date('10/19/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') SERVICE_DATE,   'DISCHARGE'    SERVICE_TYPE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  select 'ABC' PERSON_ID, to_date('10/25/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') SERVICE_DATE,   'DISCHARGE'    SERVICE_TYPE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  select 'ABC' PERSON_ID, to_date('11/21/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') SERVICE_DATE,   'INTAKE'       SERVICE_TYPE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  select 'ABC' PERSON_ID, to_date('12/03/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') SERVICE_DATE,   'INTAKE'       SERVICE_TYPE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  select 'ABC' PERSON_ID, to_date('12/06/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') SERVICE_DATE,   'INTAKE'       SERVICE_TYPE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  select 'ABC' PERSON_ID, to_date('12/26/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') SERVICE_DATE,   'DISCHARGE'    SERVICE_TYPE FROM DUAL
),
param as (
  SELECT T.*, rownum rn
  FROM (
    select t1.*, LAG(SERVICE_TYPE, 1, 'DISCHARGE') OVER (ORDER BY SERVICE_DATE) BEFORE_ROW 
    from test_table t1
  ) t
  where
    T.SERVICE_TYPE = 'INTAKE'     AND
    T.BEFORE_ROW   = 'DISCHARGE'
)
select 
  tt1.person_id     PERSON_ID,
  tt1.service_date  INTAKE,
  (SELECT MAX(T3.SERVICE_DATE) FROM TEST_TABLE T3 WHERE T3.SERVICE_TYPE = 'DISCHARGE' AND (T3.SERVICE_DATE < TT2.SERVICE_DATE OR TT2.SERVICE_DATE IS NULL)) DISCHARGE
from 
param TT1, 
param TT2
WHERE 
  TT2.SERVICE_DATE(+) > TT1.SERVICE_DATE 
ORDER BY tt1.SERVICE_DATE;